# Quarkus redis client throwing error 'java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: io.vertx.core.impl.NoStackTraceThrowable: No more endpoints in chain.'

Tags: java, kubernetes, redis, quarkus, redis-sentinel

We're trying to move from standalone redis to redis High availability mode. However while load testing in dev environment we're receiving below error.

```
    level=ERROR time="07-03-2023 20:54:35" traceId="5a65a85d2f6ccaa8" logger=GlobalExceptionMapper message="GlobalExceptionMapper: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: io.vertx.core.impl.NoStackTraceThrowable: No more endpoints in chain.
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniBlockingAwait.await(UniBlockingAwait.java:73)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniAwait.atMost(UniAwait.java:61)
        at io.quarkus.redis.client.runtime.RedisClientImpl.await(RedisClientImpl.java:1026)
        at io.quarkus.redis.client.runtime.RedisClientImpl.set(RedisClientImpl.java:672)
        at io.quarkus.redis.client.RedisClient_761b9a6e5f634178e3291b09c1921f229025da0c_Synthetic_ClientProxy.set(RedisClient_761b9a6e5f634178e3291b09c1921f229025da0c_Synthetic_ClientProxy.zig:2298)
        at <package>.services.SequenceService.isKeyPresentForDuplicityCheck(SequenceService.java:34)
        at <package>.services.SequenceService_ClientProxy.isKeyPresentForDuplicityCheck(SequenceService_ClientProxy.zig:256)
        at <package>.services.AccountsApiServiceImpl.createCustomerAccount(AccountsApiServiceImpl.java:128)
        at <package>.services.AccountsApiServiceImpl_Subclass.createCustomerAccount$$superforward1(AccountsApiServiceImpl_Subclass.zig:197)
        at <package>.services.AccountsApiServiceImpl_Subclass$$function$$2.apply(AccountsApiServiceImpl_Subclass$$function$$2.zig:33)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:54)
        at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.invokeInOurTx(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:132)
        at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.invokeInOurTx(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:103)
        at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorRequired.doIntercept(TransactionalInterceptorRequired.java:38)
        at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:57)
        at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorRequired.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorRequired.java:32)
        at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorRequired_Bean.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorRequired_Bean.zig:340)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:41)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:41)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:32)
        at <package>.services.AccountsApiServiceImpl_Subclass.createCustomerAccount(AccountsApiServiceImpl_Subclass.zig:404)
        at <package>.services.AccountsApiServiceImpl_ClientProxy.createCustomerAccount(AccountsApiServiceImpl_ClientProxy.zig:659)
        at <package>.resources.AccountsApi.createCustomerAccount(AccountsApi.java:48)
        at <package>.resources.AccountsApi$quarkusrestinvoker$createCustomerAccount_0b915408532d6a09a8c6a63ae490a49fe854ecb6.invoke(AccountsApi$quarkusrestinvoker$createCustomerAccount_0b915408532d6a09a8c6a63ae490a49fe854ecb6.zig:39)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.InvocationHandler.handle(InvocationHandler.java:29)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.InvocationHandler.handle(InvocationHandler.java:7)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:141)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$13.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:543)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
        at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
        at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
        at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.JavaThreads.threadStartRoutine(JavaThreads.java:567)
        at com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixJavaThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixJavaThreads.java:192)
Caused by: io.vertx.core.impl.NoStackTraceThrowable: No more endpoints in chain.
```

**How load testing is being performed?**

We're calling posting 30K requests from JMeter with below configuration. While the requests are being processed, we delete the redis master instance one by one (when the previously deleted pod is completely restarted).
The master redis instance is deleted using below command
`kubectl -n <namespace> delete pod redis-0`

Sentinels are able to perform a complete failover when a master redis instance is deleted and a new redis master is selected. In most cases, a few requests are failed and after a short period of time new requests start executing successfully. However, for some cases, the Jmeter hangs for a while and then the error 'io.vertx.core.impl.NoStackTraceThrowable: No more endpoints in chain' is shown for every remaining request.

[image]

**System Configuration**

Quarkus Process which is connecting to redis

[image]

All the configuration are present in process' application.properties file

Redis
[image]

Sentinel
[image]

**Things we've tried**

- Tuning the quarkus redis parameters while load testing. We've executed the load test about 20 times now with changes in redis paramters. All but 1 load tests have resulted in this issue
- There is a way to reconnect on error in vertx redis client. Abandoned this approach as there was lot of code change involved to migrate to vertx redis client

**Quarkus Process Details**

- Traffic of ~300 tps is expected on this api
- 1 pod was running in dev environment while load testing. In production, there are 5.
- Quarkus version: <quarkus.platform.version>2.3.0.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
- Redis dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-redis-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

- Last time we observed this issue was when we provided incorrect connection string to sentinel
- Redis configuration in the process. These values are overridden by the values in kubernetes deployment file

```
quarkus.redis.hosts=redis://sentinel:5000
quarkus.redis.client-type=sentinel
quarkus.redis.password=
quarkus.redis.timeout=5S
quarkus.redis.max-pool-size=50
quarkus.redis.max-pool-waiting=5000
quarkus.redis.pool-cleaner-interval=5S
quarkus.redis.pool-recycle-timeout=5S
quarkus.redis.reconnect-attempts=5
quarkus.redis.reconnect-interval=30S
quarkus.redis.max-waiting-handlers=20
```

I'm seeking assistance on how to resolve this issue as I've exhausted all ideas to resolve it. I would appreciate any guidance on the matter, including suggestions on load testing methods and configurations.

**Update**

1. Tried load testing by crashing the redis master instances through liveness probe. Same issue observed again. After crashing the pods twice the error was thrown.
2. Added below parameters for load testing. Still facing the same error

```
quarkus.redis.timeout.connect=60_000
quarkus.redis.timeout.read=70_000
quarkus.redis.timeout.write=80_000
```

Increased the timeout for redis

```
quarkus.redis.timeout=100S
```

3. Workaround done through Jedis library. This library reconnects to redis master automatically. There's probably some issue with quarkus redis client

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the Redis client couldn't get the master address for the endpoints you specified in your config and there is no more endpoint to use for that.

You use the host `sentinel` as a endpoint for Redis, is this available ?

Try this :

```
redis-cli -h sentinel -p 5000 sentinel GET-MASTER-ADDR-BY-NAME mymaster
```

`mymaster` is the name of the sentinel master. This is the default value for Quarkus.

It should work if your Quarkus config is OK. Maybe you will see a explicit error to help you.

Comment: Hello, thank you for taking the time to respond. We have implemented a workaround for this issue by utilizing the Jedis library instead of the Quarkus Redis client. With Jedis, reconnection occurs automatically, and we have observed that the API's throughput has doubled since the implementation.